# Single word request describing civic development or status

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for a word that has the same contextual purpose as "economy" in the following sentence.

> The Chamber of Commerce enacted policies intended to encourage, improve, and expand the community's economy.

The word would encompass city or community beautification, planning, expansion, resident or citizen moral, etc. As the word "economy" encompasses the idea that living in the community is desirable in that it's profitable (available jobs, good salaries, etc.), the word I'm looking for describes the idea that living in the community is desirable in that it's a pleasant place to live, the area is clean, well maintained, and effort is made to make it beautiful (flowers, trees, paint...), the people are nice, there are local festivals and night life, the schools are good, and the local government doesn't have any outstanding scandals.

In the end, the word should fill in the following space:

> The Chamber of Commerce enacted policies intended to encourage, improve, and expand the community's _______.

Comment: Sounds like *desirability*, *reputation*, or *cache*.

Comment: *Infrastructure*?

Answer (score 1):

**Development** can have these connotations. From the [Cambridge dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/development):

> **Development**
>
> - *the process in which someone or something grows or changes and becomes more advanced*
> - *the planned increase of a country’s industry and wealth*

The phrase ***Community* development** specifically can be used as an umbrella term encompassing the concepts you describe, including social, economic, cultural, environmental and political development [[wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_development).

You can use it like:

> Beautification is a key aspect of community development [[source]](https://www.beefmagazine.com/americancowman/cowman-commentary/0708-beautification-projects-community-pride)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use *infrastructure*.

> **Infrastructure:** The basic structure of an organization or system which is necessary for its operation, esp. public water, energy, and systems for communication and transport
> [[**Cambridge English dictionary**]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/infrastructure)

In your example:

> The Chamber of Commerce enacted policies intended to encourage, improve, and expand the community's *infrastructure*.

---

*Liveability* also works well in this context.

> **Liveability:** The degree to which a place is suitable or good for living in.
>
> Example: Fixing the walkways will enhance the liveability of the area.
> [[**Cambridge English dictionary**]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/liveability)

In your example, you can say:

> The Chamber of Commerce enacted policies intended to encourage, improve, and expand the community's *liveability*.

Other words like
*[amenity](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amenity)*, *[gentrification](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gentrification)* (I'm not so sure about this one), *[welfare](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/welfare)*, *[vitality](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vitality)* and *[ambience](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ambience)* could also be used.